# How to remove button focus in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus

In my HTML source code, I have a button. 
When I click the button, a `blur()` method is called to remove the focus of the clicked button. But Internet explorer 11 and 10 don't remove the focus highlight of the clicked button, even if I click on an another button.

Here's an example:

```js
function foo(event) {
  event = window.event || event;
  event_target = event.srcElement || event.target;

  //Remove the focus of the clicked button :
  event_target.blur();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="5" onclick="foo(event);">
<input type="button" value="6" onclick="foo(event);">
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for us to try the effect, since it does not sound familiar.

Comment: Works for me on IE11.

Comment: Side note: You don't need the `event = windows.event || event;` thing in `foo`. Because of the way you're calling it, you can reliably use the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find the problem. It's in the css, add it : 
`<style type="text/css">
 
.ban_title:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

</style>`

in this snippet, this css avoid the focus removing : IE is very bad ! Can you confirm that ?